# Как сделать проверку деления на 0 в языке Golang

Tags: golang, исключения, деление

Извините за глупый вопрос, я знаю что в языке Go нет исключений, но меня интересует как сделать такой код Go?

```
try {


     const x = 0;
        const y = 10;
        if(x == 0 || y == 0){
            throw new Error("Divide by zero error");
        } else {
            alert(y / x)
        }
    } catch (e){
        alert(e.message);
    }
```

Comment: В чём проблема?  Верните ошибку и всё.

Comment: А как такой код написать на Go ?(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang не имеет механизмов исключений и, соответственно, `try..catch`, но имеет механизм паники, как уже сказал @Mark
Для обработки ошибок в Golang присутствует тип error. Вам необходимо будет проверять значение на 0 и, если оно таковое, возвращать эту ошибку и обрабатывать ее:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

var (
    // Используя тот самый механизм ошибок создаем нашу ошибку
    divError = errors.New("Divide by zero error")
)

func main() {
    // Отработает корректно и мы получим в ответе 5
    // в err будет пустота - nil
    intRes, err := intdiv(10, 2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(intRes)
    }   

    // В intRes у нас будет 0, а вот в err будет лежать ранее созданная ошибка 
    intRes, err = intdiv(10, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(intRes)
    }   
}

// Специфика Golang такова, что мы можем либо получить interface{} как любой тип (но тогда нам придется обрабатывать тип переменных в самой функции и после получения результата), либо указывать тип
func intdiv(a int, b int) (int, error) {
    if b == 0 {
        return 0, divideError
    }

    return a / b, nil
}
```

[Попробуйте тут](https://play.golang.com/p/ReGvhFhAP7k)

Comment: Спасибо,вам за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит паттерны Java один в один переносить на Go, но если вопрос стоит именно так -  можно попробовать.

В Go есть механизм паники, похожий на исключения в Java, возникшую панику можно отловить и преобразовать в ошибку.
Для этого нужно блок кода из `try{что-то полезное}` оформить в виде возвращающей ошибку  анонимной функции `func() (err error) {что-то полезное}()`, а затем эту ошибку обработать как захочется.

```
err := func() (err error) {

    // это примерный аналог try
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err = r.(error)
        }
    }()

    // место для полезного кода, я выделил его {}, но только чтобы более явно показать его границы
    {
        a := 1
        b := 0
        fmt.Printf("Сейчас выполним допустимую операцию %d \n", a+b)
        fmt.Printf("Сейчас выполним недопустимую операцию %d \n", a/b)
        fmt.Printf("И еще одну допустимую  %d \n", a+b)
    }

    return

}()

// эта часть кода похожа на catch, если предыдущая функция вернула ненулевую ошибку, то ее можно как-то обработать
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hX8nj7RbaBz

На выводе в консоль видно, что функция успешно выполнила первую корректную операцию и сразу закончила работу после второй (некорректной) не дойдя до третьей. Появившаяся при этом паника могла закончить работу всего приложения, если бы не была обработана функцией `recover`.

В таком виде это больше похоже на трюк, а не рабочий код. Если что то может упасть или сработать неправильно - лучше просто оформить это в виде обычной функции, возвращающей ошибку.

Comment: Интересный вариант, спасибо !